# Retrieve an image from Office 365 into an iOS app

Tags: ios, image, sharepoint, office365, sdwebimage

Does anyone know how to retrieve an image from Office 365 into an iOS app?

The image logo has the following returned format:
https://"TENANT".sharepoint.com/"SITE NAME"/SiteAssets/domain1.png

I've implemented a custom Web API to retrieve the site collections. A specific site might have a logo and from my iOS app I could get its url after calling the service.

The problem is that I receive 401 or 403 for getting the image no matter if I pass or not the obtained token for the Web Api call as an authorisation header.

```
SDWebImageDownloader *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager].imageDownloader;
[manager setValue:authHeader forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];


[logo sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:site.logo] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cross"] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=401 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error 401.)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to develop a custom Web API and pass the credentials using **SharePointOnlineCredentials**.